# Managing ratingbars on small sceens

Tags: android, ratingbar

[image]

How to manage rating bar stars in small screen i have already use `scalx` and `scaly`  and style but facing same problem . showing only 4 stars in small size screen

```
<RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:numStars="5"
                    android:scaleX="0.6"
                    android:scaleY="0.6"
                    android:theme="@style/MyRatingBar"
                    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_stars"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView229"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView228" />
```

using small size showing

```
style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
```

[image]

Comment: Dont scale the rating bar, rather make its width to `match_parent` and give your height some fixed value.